# Why Continue in While loop is not working in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, continue

Hello while I was practicing while loop in Python my code was not giving any outputs whatsoever. I am learning python from books only, so it may sound basic: but where is the problem in this code? I was trying to print integers less than 100 which are not divisible by 5.

```
x=0
while (x<101):
    if (x%5==0):
        continue
    
    print (x, end=" ")
    x=x+1
```

I was trying to print integers less than 100 which are not divisible by 5

Comment: You're skipping over the `x = x + 1`, so you get stuck at the same value of `x`.

Comment: You can flip the condition and do away with the `continue` altogether: `if x % 5 != 0: print (x, end=" ")` and/or use a `for` loop.

Comment: I placed it before if statement now it is running. but when I am placing the 'x=x+1' below it is getting skipped. Why?

Comment: Thank you. I am getting result.

Comment: Debug tip: Put a `print(x)` just after the while to see what happens to that variable. You can remove it when the code works.

Comment: As an aside, `while x < 101:` is fine. The `while` doesn't need parens.

Comment: Part of practicing `while` loops, though, should be recognizing when it's *not* the right solution. I would write this code with a `for` loop instead: `for x in range(0, 101, 5): print(x, end=" ")`.

Comment: yes I have written it with for loop and with and without continue statement. But when I could not solve I tried to know, why I could not solve. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

`continue` goes back to the beginning of the loop, skipping over the rest of the body. This means it skips over `x = x + 1`. So you keep testing the same value of `x`.

Instead of a `while` loop, use a `for` loop, so the increment isn't in the body that you skip over.

```
for x in range(100):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        continue

    print(x, end=" ")
```

If you really want to use `while` and `continue`, you can duplicate the code that increments `x`.

```
while x < 101:
    if x % 5 == 0:
        x += 1
        continue

    print(x, end=" ")
    x += 1
```

Or you could move the increment before the test

```
while x < 101:
    x += 1
    if x % 5 == 1:
        continue

    print(x-1, end=" ")
```

But notice that this makes it more complicated because you have to subtract 1 when printing to get the value from before the increment.

Comment: yes I could easily solve it with for and range. But I was getting stuck at while loop.

Comment: I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try stepping through your code with a debugger before posting a question here. If you had done this you would have found the problem right away.

Your code gets stuck in an infinite loop. Try this:

```
x=0
while (x<101):
    if (x%5 != 0):
        print (x, end=" ")
    x=x+1
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to solve a problem using both continue statement and while loop. I tried both the suggestions in the comment before posting here. Thanks BTW.

Comment: @SanjibDeyChoudhury There is no reason to solve this using a `while` loop and `continue`.

Comment: by being stubborn I just clarified one of my misconceptions. So, it is good to be stubborn sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You got an infinite loop on execution...

when x is 0, it's true, the loop continue on next execution
but x is not incremented. So on the next loop execution, the same result: 0 % 5 == 0 returns true

Solution: increment x before the continue;

so you'll have:

```
x=0
while (x<101):
if (x%5==0):
    x=x+1
    continue

print (x, end=" ")
x=x+1
```

This should be fine !